# How to choose the resolved activity for the given set of intents programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've two activities something like this,

```html
<activity android:name=".activities.TripuraActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_tripura"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM_A"></action>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM_B"></action>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.NagalandActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_nagaland"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM_A"></action>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM_B"></action>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.CUSTOM_C"></action>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now when I start my activity with something like this,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction("android.intent.action.CUSTOM_A");
  intent.setAction("android.intent.action.CUSTOM_B");
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
  this.startActivity(intent);
```

When I do this when I launch the app both, `TripuraActivity` and `NagalandActivity` comes on UI with a resolver dialog. How do I avoid this, is there a way to resolve this programmatically in Andriod?

Comment: you dont need to write "android.intent.action.CUSTOM_A". you can simply write "CUSTOM_A" in both place. send intent and in manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which activity to open:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,NagalandActivity.class);
```